# Is there a way to observe whether a checkbox in a container of checkboxes is checked and disable all the checkboxes in that container if so?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm building an interface in Jupyter Notebook, and for one of the questions being asked (there is a VBox consisting of a Label with the value being the name of the question), users should only be able to select one of the choices. Since I am asking multiple questions, and some of the questions allow multiple answers, I am using a checkbox because I do not know how to make the vertical radio buttons have consistent spacing with the other checkboxes.

[image: A screen shot of my UI showing a grid of checkboxes with three columns and many rows]

this image gives an idea of what the layout looks like.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the checkboxes in a list and call a function every time any of those checkboxes are changed.

For example:

```
def onCheckBoxChanged(event):
    widget = event['owner']
    for checkbox in groupby_checkboxes:
        if checkbox != widget:
            checkbox.value = False

groupby_checkboxes = []
for i in range(4):
    new = widgets.Checkbox(value=False)
    new.observe(onCheckBoxChanged, names=['value'])
```